# Implementing an Object type in C++

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

I'm currently working through the "[Crafting Interpreters](https://craftinginterpreters.com/)" book by Robert Nystrom. He uses Java to implement the visitor pattern in which the visitor functions return the Object type. C++ doesn't support an Object type so my solution was to create a polymorphic type in c++ using virtual functions and inheritance

I'm just curious about the drawbacks of my implementation and how it could be implemented better:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Object {
public:
    virtual std::string getType() const = 0;
};

class String : public Object {
private:
    std::string value;

public:
    String(const std::string& val) : value(val) {}

    std::string getType() const override {
        return "string";
    }

    std::string getValue() const {
        return value;
    }
};

class Double : public Object {
private:
    double value;

public:
    Double(double val) : value(val) {}

    std::string getType() const override {
        return "double";
    }

    double getValue() const {
        return value;
    }
};
```

Comment: The obvious drawback is now you have to reimplement every class ever. Also, there's almost no advantage whatsoever. There's a *reason* C++ doesn't have this.

Comment: I’m only reimplementing about 5-6 basic classes - String, Double, Boolean and a couple others

Comment: Notes on question tagging: The code is not Java and the question is unrelated to Java. Do not tag it with Java. The code uses C++11 features but the question is not asking about those features. Do not tag it with C++11.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @273K While this may be on-topic on CR, in the future, please don't use the existence of the Code Review site as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *Needs more focus*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353)

Comment: You're missing a lot of methods https://ideone.com/fmKWXA

Comment: In Java you use `Object` because it exists and it is convenient. In C++ you would rather create a more limited `DataType` base class used *only* for these types.

Comment: there is nothing wrong about using inheritance and virtual functions to implement an interpreter, however this will run much slower than java because java uses JIT to de-virtualize its calls because the machine code is generated at runtime instead of compile time, this is not something C++ compilers do very often, and don't mistake this for being C++ performance, this is more like a poor java implementation than c++.

Comment: `std::variant` or `std::any` may be of interest to you.  There are other ways to do this other than polymorphism and dynamic allocation.